# Is there anything unsafe about this log function?

Tags: c, winapi

```
void add_log(const char* format, ...)
{
    HANDLE filehandle;
    DWORD dwReadBytes;
    char buffer[2048];
    char writebuffer[2048];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf_s(buffer, format, args);
    filehandle = CreateFile("C:\\Log.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
    SetFilePointer(filehandle, 0, 0, FILE_END);
    time_t ltime;
    ltime = time(NULL);
    //sprintf_s(writebuffer, 2048, "%s: %s\n", asctime(localtime(&ltime)), buffer);
    sprintf_s(writebuffer, 2048, "%s", buffer);
    WriteFile(filehandle, writebuffer, strlen(writebuffer), &dwReadBytes, 0);
    CloseHandle(filehandle);
}
```

I had a friend introduce this bit of code and I've used it across multiple versions. I mainly used it to debug certain functions but started to use it as a regular way to log certain things internally, but I feel like it causes problems under certain instances like when I use them in threads or functions that get called very often. Is there anything unsafe about how this function works?

Comment: need open log file once, or say once per  day. not need `SetFilePointer`, use `FILE_APPEND_DATA` instead `GENERIC_WRITE`. second `sprintf_s` is absolute senseless. etc

Answer (score 2):

1. You're not doing any error-checking or error-handling, so for example if `CreateFile()` failed and returned `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE`, then the code would pass an invalid file handle value to the other functions, which is probably not what you want.
2. You're opening a new file-handle on every call, writing one line of text into the file, and then closing the file-handle again.  That is likely to be inefficient, especially if this function is being called often.
3. If the function is called from multiple threads, then the file will be written to by multiple threads in parallel, possibly causing `CreateFile()` to fail and/or garbled data within the file (depending on how gracefully the filesystem handles unsynchronized writes to the same file)
4. If your format-string expands to more than 2048 characters, then `sprintf_s()` or `vsprintf_s()` will invoke the Win32 runtime's [invalid-parameter-handling function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation?view=msvc-170), which by default will abort your program with an error message -- possibly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll adjust according to these issues and try to find a more efficient approach.

Comment: The question is *specifically* asking about safety issues. None of the ones named here are. Clearly down-vote material, even after removing the hilarious *"I don't know what I'm talking about"* statements.

Comment: When I come across a question where the existing answers are unsatisfying, I don't bother with snide comments; rather I come up with the answer that I think *should* be posted there, and I post it.  Perhaps you can do the same, here.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't generally waste time going up against up-voted answers. There is substantial historic evidence that up-votes win over correctness. There's also historic evidence that Windows doesn't fall into your area of expertise. This isn't the first time you demonstrate a complete lack of insight into a basic construct (such as opaque handle values).